# Class '...' must be declared as 'abstract'. Checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle

I have this warning on most of my classes and not sure why is that. This happens on both public normal classes and final classes which have private constructors, some no constructor at all. I tried changing my private class methods to protected, doesn't help.
 Any suggestions on how to turn this off?

Here's a class example

```
public final class PlanBenefitManagerAssembler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PlanBenefitManagerAssembler.class);

    /**
     * No Instance of the this class is allowed.
     */
    private PlanBenefitManagerAssembler() {

    }

    public static List<BenefitDecisionDetailsBean> assembleBenefitDecisionDetailsBean(
            List<BenefitDetails> benefitDecisionDetailsList, int relationalSequenceNumber) {

        LOGGER.debug("Enter assembleBenefitDecisionDetailsBean");
        List<BenefitDecisionDetailsBean> benefitDecisionDetailsBeanList = new ArrayList<BenefitDecisionDetailsBean>();

        for (BenefitDetails benefitDecisionDetails : benefitDecisionDetailsList) {
            BenefitDecisionDetailsBean benefitDecisionDetailsBean = new BenefitDecisionDetailsBean();
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitTypeCode(benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitTypeCode());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setRelationSequenceNumber(relationalSequenceNumber);
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitStatusDescription(
                    benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitStatusDescription());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitStatusCode(benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitStatusCode());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitUnderwritingStatusCode(
                    benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitUnderwritingStatusCode());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitUnderwritingStatusDescription(
                    benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitUnderwritingStatusDescription());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitChangeReasonCode(
                    String.valueOf(benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitChangeReasonCode()));
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitChangeReasonDescription(
                    benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitChangeReasonDescription());
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setComponentNumber(benefitDecisionDetails.getBenefitNumber());

            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setBenefitVisible(benefitDecisionDetails.isExplicitBenefitDecisionRequired());

            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setModelChanged(false);

            // * Set BenefitLoading and BenefitExclusion
            List<ExclusionDetailsBean> exclusionDetailsBeanList =
                    PlanBenefitManagerAssembler.assembleExclusionDetailsList(benefitDecisionDetails
                            .getBenefitExclusionsDetailsList().getBenefitExclusionsDetailsList());

            List<LoadingDetailsBean> loadingDetailsBeanList =
                    PlanBenefitManagerAssembler.assembleLoadingDetailsList(benefitDecisionDetails
                            .getBenefitLoadingsDetailsList().getBenefitLoadingsDetailsList());

            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setExclusionDetailsBeanList(exclusionDetailsBeanList);
            benefitDecisionDetailsBean.setLoadingDetailsBeanList(loadingDetailsBeanList);

            benefitDecisionDetailsBeanList.add(benefitDecisionDetailsBean);         
        }

        LOGGER.debug("Exit assembleBenefitDecisionDetailsBean");

        return benefitDecisionDetailsBeanList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Add the code that causes that warning. BTW what IDE you are using?

Comment: Find the warning in the [Checkstyle documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html) where it should explain why you get this.

Comment: not sure but i would think that checstyle is looking to see if the class is instantiable with a public construcor and if not is saying to itself 'well it must be an abstract class yet it hasn't been declared abstract so lets warn the user'

Comment: @MockerTim: why would the IDE be relevant? Java code is Java code, and Checkstyle is IDE-agnostic.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not familiar with Checkstyle, but if it uses plugins for IDE integration, it depends on IDE. Anyway, IDE info doesn't complicate the question. :)

Comment: @MockerTim: So, if I use a plugin to generate my hashCode and equals methods, you need to know which IDE is used if I have a bug in my equals method? Checkstyle generates warnings about Java code, and whatever you use to see these warnings, the warnings mean the same thing. The IDE is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @MockerTim, i have both IBM RSA 8 and Eclipse Indigo using the same checkstyle 5.0.3 ... Strange that am only getting this warning on eclipse not RSA. So your IDE suspicions could be true.

Comment: @JBNizet Of course it depends on specific case. Nothing to argue about.

Comment: @sonx So, what about some code?

Comment: @sonx: you just enabled a different set of rules in both IDEs. What is the name of the rule triggering this warning? Have you looked up its description in the Checkstyle documentation?

Comment: Please, add a screenshot of the warning to your post. Like in [this example](http://www.sickboy.cz/checkstyle/screenshots.html).

Comment: Maybe, the easiest way to solve your problem is to install the latest version of Checkstyle plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: @sonx: are you sure that you're not looking at a warning which was generated for an older version of this class?

Comment: By the way, for what you are doing in the class manually, you could also let Dozer do this for you: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ There will not be much you would have to configure.

Answer (score 3):

You can always turn the warnings off, but they generally are here for a reason :)

- Do you intend to make them abstract classes ? If so, declare them that way.
- Will you need to instantiate them at some point ? If so, add a public constructor.

I'm pretty sure this will solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Silver, i don't intend having them as abstract classes. I did try public constructor, no change.

Comment: I'm surprised it suggests you make it abstract. Judging by your code, I would make it static. It's an utility class, from what I understand. No instance needed, only provide static methods ? Static class. But that's not an answer to your actual problem. I'll check Checkstyle's documentation but I never stumbled upon your problem.

Comment: A non-inner class can't be static.

Comment: I'm mixing my labguages. My bad. Vote up for pointing me the obvious, good sir.

Answer (score 3):

When Checkstyle produces a warning the warning text should include a short rule name which will allow you to look up the exact rule that is being triggered. "DesignForExtension", for example.

Given the rule name, you can look up more detail on what it means in the Checkstyle documentation:  http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/availablechecks.html

Post the full details of the rule being triggered and someone might be able to help.

Comment: The warning doesn't include any warning info, type or name. I tried hovering the mouse over the warning. Only the message is displayed

Comment: @sonx I've installed Checkstyle plugin for NetBeans. I also don't have any rule description.

Comment: A bit of searching brings up [https://github.com/eclipse/jubula.core/tree/96522240c6e8c92a9e85ab0937db9b26fcc9fa19/org.eclipse.jubula.project.configuration] which suggests a) it's the AbstractClassName rule you're triggering and b) that you might have come across a bug in Checkstyle.

Comment: Do you have a checkstyle.xml file when using it in NetBeans? I am only familiar with the Eclipse plugin.

Comment: @Tim i'm using eclipse also yes i have the xml. I've checked in the code on svn will ask if my colleague experiences the same on his WS. Could be a bug

Answer (score 1):

On [sourceforge](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_naming.html) it says that the AbstractClassName rule uses the following regex:

```
^Abstract.*$|^.*Factory$
```

This causes classes with a name starting with 'Abstract' or ending with 'Factory' to be flagged. I get the 'Abstract..' part of that, but why should all '..Factory' classes be abstract? Sometimes I create factories which use dependencies to do their work so I need an instance to inject into.

This however does not explain your case. I tried your example class and did not get any Checkstyle warning (I am using the Eclipse Checkstyle Plug-in version 5.3.0.201012121300).

Are you sure you are getting the AbstractClassName warning for this class? Which version of Checkstyle are you using?

Comment: Maybe is should add a screenshot here but don't know how to. any guidelines would be helpful

Comment: In Eclipse go to Help -> About Eclipse SDK -> installation details -> Plugins and look up the version of the Checkstyle plugin. For the warning, just recheck that your class really results in the AbstractClassName warning, not some other warning.